# Codeigniter form validation undefined property

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i'm trying to validate my form using codeigniter validator and it shows this weird error? [image]

i have autoloaded the form validator library and helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form','text');
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation', 'session');
```

so why would it throw undefined property?
here is my controller

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller
{
public function register()
{
    //fields username,email,password1,password2
    // $this->load->view('templates/header');
    // $this->load->view('user/register');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|max_length[50]|is_unique[users.username]|trim|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_valdiation->set_rules('email','Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2','Confirm password','trim|required|matches[password1]');
    if($this->validation->run === false)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('user/register');
    } else {

    }
}
```

}
what am i exactly doign wrong?

Comment: You need to include the dependencies inside your class constructor, or within the controller method itself.

Comment: Is your library extending `CI_Controller`? If not, you'll need to inherent from the parent's class.

Comment: @Kaylined tried that still doesn't work :X. kisaragi i'm sorry but what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Did you tried $this->load->library('Form_validation') inside controller constructor ??

Comment: @Florin yes.. still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo in the second rule:

```
$this->form_valdiation->set_rules
```

It must be: form_validation

Also, you need the () to call the validation function:

```
$this->form_validation->run()
```

Hope it hepls.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$this->validation->run
```

Try

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
```

The controller [example](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller)

And

```
public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```

Comment: Did you name Filename User,php not user.php