# There is a error in my form_validation in code igniter 3 it has a red line under it when i hover my mouse on in it says unindentified property

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I already added it to my autoload

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation','session', 'pagination');
          $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','text');
```

Here is the controller code where I am going to use the set_rules function on my form validation.

```
public function register()
              {
                   $this->load->library('form_validation');
                   $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','trim|required|alpha');
              }
```

tried re-adding the form_validation to the autoload libraries

I don't really know what to do at this point currently a newbie at using code igniter.

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680912/codeigniter-form-validation-undefined-property. There might be a typo in your code, but we don't know. So please add a MRE: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also post the complete error message as text, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because your controller and its parent classes do not have a `form_validation` property in their source code.

If you look at the source code for `CI_Controller` (your controller should be extending `CI_Controller`) you can see that this is true, but `CI_Controller` also allows you to load libraries via its `load` property.

When you call `$this->load->library('form_validation')` this then (during script execution) creates a new property on `CI_Controller` for the library you've requested (`form_validation` in this case), which you can then use.

But since this property is added dynamically and is not in the source code, your code editor can't know about it, thinks you're making a mistake and gives you the error.

So you can ignore the error in this case, your code should work!