# How can I fix the 'Undefined property' warning message for the 'Pegawai_model' in my CodeIgniter controller?

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
public function ubahPassword()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[5]', [
            'min_length' => 'Password minimum 5 character'
        ]);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data['title'] = 'Ubah Password';
            $this->load->view('admin/layout/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('admin/layout/side');
            $this->load->view('admin/layout/side-header');
            $this->load->view('admin/pegawai/ubahPassword');
            $this->load->view('admin/layout/footer');
        } else {
            $data = $this->Pegawai_model->ubahPassword();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Password Berhasil Diganti!
           </div>');
            redirect('admin/ubahPassword');
        }
    }
```

ini apa yang salah ya?

Comment: Does the answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191893/there-is-a-error-in-my-form-validation-in-code-igniter-3-it-has-a-red-line-under