# yellow line under form_validation library in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

yellow line under form_validation library in codeigniter

i dont know why this happen
this is the function where the yellow lne appears...

```
public function form_validation()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','required|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name','Last Name','required|alpha');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
         {
        $this->load->model('main_model');
         }
         else{
        $this->index();
         }

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191893/there-is-a-error-in-my-form-validation-in-code-igniter-3-it-has-a-red-line-under/76194743#76194743